# In redux when writing thunks for dispatch, what's the difference between "next" and "store.dispatch"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In the video lesson: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-dispatching-actions-asynchronously-with-thunks we learn to write our own thunks so that we can have asynchronous & multiple calls of dispatch in an action creator. I understand this for the most part.

However, I am confused at why we used `store.dispatch` instead of `next` in the thunk:

```
const thunk = (store) => (next) => (action) =>
  typeof action === 'function' ?
    action(store.dispatch) :
    next(action);
```

Why would one use `next` versus `store.dispatch` and vice versa? I understand that `next` advances to the next middleware but if the next middleware eventually also calls dispatch, why would I use `store.dispatch` over `next`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already pointed out, `next` only calls the next middleware in the chain. Although it does eventually call the original dispatch function, it isn't appropriate to use it when you want to traverse the whole chain again. In the case of thunks, you want to traverse the whole chain.

So, if you're creating a middleware where you want to do some work and then continue down the chain, use `next`. For example, the logger does this: it logs the action, calls `next`, and then logs the resulting state. To return a callback that will traverse the whole chain, return `store.dispatch`. It seems unlikely that you would want to return `next` from a middleware, since you would probably assume that you don't know which middlewares come before and after the current one, so the outcome of calling it outside of the middleware chain is unpredictable.